Regarding proxyfing the windows connection through tor
My OS is mainly windows, and I've experimenting using tor for quite sometime.
When I use tor in expectation to torrify the whole system, I go to Internet Options settings, and use a proxy server for LAN connection and have these configurations:
My Internet Options
And my tor configurations (I am using torGUI from github):
tor Conf
I checked my IP address from my browser and yes I am indeed using tor network. But then, when I go to cmd and type curl ifconfig.me it shows me my real ip address... What? Why?
Do you guys know the answer? Or perhaps is it because that the command above uses a protocol that tor does not support..?
Any feedback is helpful. Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
